# Fighting the touchstart event delay on iOS

Tags: ios, touch, kineticjs, touchstart

I'm experiencing a ~500ms delay in Safari for iOS when binding the `touchstart` event to a KineticJS circle object. I've tried calling `event.preventDefault()` within the `on` function, thinking that this would override the default iOS behavior, but it made no difference. I'm not sure whether this has anything to do with KineticJS, which is why I left that out of the title (but included it as a tag). Note: there is no delay using the iOS simulator – the delay is only happening on the actual device (iPhone 4). Any ideas?

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: $(window).width(),
    height: $(window).height(),
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 70,
    fill: "black",
});

layer.add(circle);
stage.add(layer);

circle.on("touchstart", function() {
    this.setFill("red");
    layer.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ~300ms delay on mobile browsers while the browser waits to see if it's a single or double tap (since double-tap is for zoom).

This can be removed on recent builds of Android devices by using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

However, Mobile Safari doesn't follow this same logic, and there's no way to disable this delay.

You can read more about this here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

Comment: This is actually not relevant, as he's binding to `touchstart` not `click`.  I'd guess that there's some logic that takes a while to compute?  Not sure, working on this issue myself.